# System.Web.UI.Page.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

Tags: c#, properties

I knew this is a newbee question but I need your help.

I have been running this site for long, when I installed VS2013 and reopen this solution, I've got this few errors. and I am no longer able to Log in.

Errors:

'System.Web.UI.Page.User' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type'

The name 'ConnectionClass' does not exist in the current context

here is my Login.cs file:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Login : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
User user = ConnectionClass.LoginUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text);

if (user != null)
{
//Store login variables in session
Session["login"] = user.Username;
Session["type"] = user.Usertype;

Response.Redirect("~/Home.aspx");
}
else
{
lblError.Text = "Login failed";
}

}
}
```

And my ConnectionClass.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public class ConnectionClass
{
private static SqlConnection conn;
private static SqlCommand command;

public static ConnectionClass()
{
string connectionString=           ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CISConnectionString"].ToString();
conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
command = new SqlCommand("", conn);
}

public static ArrayList GetPOByType(string Customertype)
{
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
string query = string.Format("SELECT * FROM PO WHERE Customertype LIKE '{0}'",     Customertype);

try
{
conn.Open();
command.CommandText = query;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    int id = reader.GetInt32(0);
    string name = reader.GetString(1);
    string type = reader.GetString(2);
    string image = reader.GetString(3);
    string review = reader.GetString(4);

PO PO = new PO(id, name, type, image, review);
list.Add(PO);
}
}
finally
{
conn.Close();
}

return list;
}


public static User LoginUser(string name, string password)
{
//Check if user exists
string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username = '{0}'", name);
command.CommandText = query;

try
{
conn.Open();
int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

if (amountOfUsers == 1)
{
//User exists, check if the passwords match
query = string.Format("SELECT Password FROM Users WHERE Username = '{0}'", name);
```

command.CommandText = query;
    string dbPassword = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

```
if (dbPassword == password)
{
//Passwords match. Login and password data are known to us.
//Retrieve further user data from the database
query = string.Format("SELECT Email, Usertype FROM Users WHERE Username = '{0}'", name);
command.CommandText = query;

SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
User user = null;

while (reader.Read())
{
string email = reader.GetString(0);
string type = reader.GetString(1);

user = new User(name, password, email, type);
}
return user;
}
else
{
//Passwords do not match
return null;
}
}
else
{
//User does not exist
return null;
}
}
finally
{

conn.Close();
}
}

public static string RegisterUser(User user)
{
//Check if user exists
string query = string.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Users WHERE Username = '{0}'", user.Username);
command.CommandText = query;

try
{
conn.Open();
int amountOfUsers = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();

if (amountOfUsers < 1)
{
//User does not exist, create a new user
query = string.Format("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}', '{3}')",     user.Username, user.Password,
user.Email, user.Usertype);
command.CommandText = query;
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
return "User registered!";
}
else
{
//User exists
return "A user with this name already exists";
}
}
finally
{
conn.Close();
}
}


}
```

Please  I really need your help.

Comment: At which row do you get the error?

Comment: Please reformat your code to make it more readable.

Answer (score 0):

`ConnectionClass` is most probably not available in the namespace you are trying to access it from (Login.cs). There is no reference to the `ConnectionClass`.

You need to either add namespaces and make sure they are both in the same or add reference to the namespace in which the ConnectionClass is located (e.g. using `MySolution.Connectivity` ).